# Moving an object that contains values

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a class like this:

```
class Bla {
private:
    size_t length;
    ComplexClass expensiveData; // Very expensive, and Bla manages everything about someStuff, including its creation and deletion
};
```

Now suppose I wanted to do something like this:

```
Bla a = ...;
Bla b = ...;

a = b;
```

Now what I think would happen is that when I assign `a` to `b`, the copy assignment operator will be called.

The thing is, if I were to deep copy the contents of `a` and `b`, it would be very expensive. It would be preferable to **always** just do a shallow copy of `Bla`.  However, the problem is that `expensiveData` is a regular value, and not a pointer, which means if I try to reassign `expensiveData` to a new object, it would just copy it.

Also, `expensiveData` is provided by one of the libraries I use, and I can't change how it works.

Should I just either:

1. Delete the copy assignment and copy constructor operators because I **never** want to do any deep copy, but then lose the ability for assignment.
2. Change `expensiveData` into a pointer, and then in the copy constructor just reassign the pointers.
3. Use another method, like `std::move`, or `std::swap`?

Comment: What is the actual, exact type of `expensiveData`? What makes it expensive to copy? ([edit] your question to include this information, rather than responding in a comment.)

Comment: `expensiveData` is some sort of tree structure that I'm using from one of my provided libraries (I can't change how it works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing a pointer to `ComplexClass` would work, but using a *raw* pointer would be unwise. Use `std::shared_ptr<ComplexClass>`.

Alternatively, you could delete the copy constructor & assignment, and then store `Bla` in `shared_ptr`s when you do need assignments.

And instead of deleteing the copy operations, you can:

- Make them private, and add a member function with a long scary name that performs them, in case you need them.
- Delete just the copy assignment, and make the copy constructor `explicit`. Then `a = b;` wouldn't compile, but `a = Bla(b);` still would.

Comment: Ah ok. I think I'm going to use the last option which is to delete the copy assignment operator but leave the copy constructor, so I can still copy it easily. Thanks!